# Binding PDFDocument to PDFView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa-bindings

I could not find the option of binding the document (of kind PDFDocument) to the PDFView in MAC programming.  I believe I can leverage custom binding to do the same.  Before I venture into that path, I thought I will check the people who ran into this issue earlier and any pointer towards identifying the missing binding info.

Comment: Which property of `PDFDocument` do you want to bind to the PDFView? Or do you want to bind the document of the view to the document or a document property of another object? `PDFView` doesn't expose a document binding.

Comment: @Willeke I am looking for the document property (probably I should have mentioned it explicitly in the question) of the PDFView

Comment: Does the document change as a result of a user action?

Comment: @Willeke No.  I have a model object which has a reference to the document and is available when the nib file of the associated view controller gets loaded.

Comment: Does the document change later on?

Comment: @Willeke Not at this moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122319/discussion-between-ios-learner-and-willeke).

Comment: You can't bind the document to the view because the document doesn't have a view property. You can't bind the view to the document because there isn't a document binding. I would set the document. If you want to track changes, use an observer.